# changing modal-close behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I got the thankfull job of debugging somebody's code who left my company a year ago. I'm new to jquery and I'm struggling with my task at hand.

The application is a store/inventory management ASP.NET app. There's an overview page, which lists all the stores. And you can edit the stores. So the function for that is:

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-open-edit-modal', function () {
    $("#EditWinkelModal").load("/Winkels/Details/" + $(this).data("id"), function () {
        $("#modal-winkel-edit").modal();
    });
});
```

which opens a modal. So far it's ok. The problem is when the user closes the modal. That can either be done by pressing the "X" in the upper right corner, pressing escape, clicking outside of the modal or pressing a button, defined as

```
<button type="button" class="c-btn c-btn--secondary" modal-close>Annuleer</button>
```

What happens is that this only hides the modal (sets 'display' to 'none'. It doesn't remove the added code. So now, when the user edits another store, more code is added to the page. and the codes clash.
Here's a picture of Chrome inspect, after I've eddited some stores (called 'winkel' in my language/Dutch)
[image]

I've figured out a way to solve this for the button. I just changed it to

```
<button type="button" class="c-btn c-btn--secondary"  id="cancelWinkelAdd">Annuleer</button>
```

and added the code

```
$(document).on('click', '#cancelWinkelEdit', function () {
    $.modal.close();
    var element = $("#modal-winkel-edit")[0];
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
});
```

But this only solves it for the button. Problem still occurs for all other close options (mentioned above). So now I'm looking at a way to overwrite this `close-modal` method.

How should I do this, or is there a better solution altogether?

Comment: I recommend a change of approach - instead of loading the whole `.modal` every time, you put a "shell" of a modal on the page at startup and then only the modal content into `.modal-body` - this way you only have a single modal to show/hide and when you edit the 2nd item it overwrites the 1st in the `.modal-body` so you never get the clash.  This approach works well for bootstrap modals, but it's not clear what modal plugin/framework you're using, so it's possible it's not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using `jQuery-modal`, `jQuery-modal` has a list of events that get fired with certain actions. You can listen for the event that is fired when the modal gets closed.

```
$.modal.AFTER_CLOSE = 'modal:after-close';
// Fires after the modal has fully closed (including animations).
```

And remove the modal from the DOM when this event is called

```
$('#example-modal').on($.modal.AFTER_CLOSE, function(event, modal) {
    modal.remove(); // <-- delete the modal from the DOM
});
```

More information can be found here: https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal#events

Comment: Thanks! I had to change it to `$(document).on($.modal.AFTER_CLOSE, '#modal-winkel-edit', function () {` and `modal.remove();` didn't do anything for me, but you pointed me in the right direction.